# Why does Mercurial show modified files on projet folder copy

Tags: mercurial

On a CentOS Linux machine, I have copied a folder project that has mercurial.

```
Hg status
```

in the source folder was clean.
Now hg status in the new folder shows modified files. Those files seem to be quasirandom: 2 php files and most of the image folder from almost a thousand files.
Of course,

```
hg diff -g
```

dows not show anything.

I've done this before to create a test instance of the same project, different branch, and everything was ok.

I've read here about modified permissions, but this is not the case. I've looked in the filesystem and all files pairs are 0644 and are identical.

Is there any other file property that is tracked by Mercurial and can be modified by a file copy command?

**Edit 1**

As it turns out,

```
hg diff --git
```

shows permissions modified from 755 to 644, but I'm looking at the files in the original folder and this is not true. All files are 644, but for reasons unknown, Mercurial thinks they are 755

**Edit 2**

So, the theory is that the old repo is somehow borked: it thinks some files are 755 while in fact they are 644.
To prove the theory I cloned the repo using hg clone and lo and behold, in the new repo all those specific files are cloned as 755.
Checked again the source: 644. Destination: 755

So much for Mercurial reliability

Comment: "So much for Mercurial reliability".  *eyeroll*  Mercurial didn't invent permissions for you.  Likely it passed through a FAT32 file system (flash drive) that borked the execute bit and you committed there.

Comment: This is no longer a question.  Maybe change it to "how do I see permissions differences?" since that's what you answered.